# move the green box to the top of the right grey box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

The following is the graph I modified from the forest style, but I encounter an problem when I try to **move the green box to the top of the right grey box**, I know the main problem is the tree style, but I couldn't figure it out, I seek for your help, thanks in advances.

My code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,fit,trees}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    basic1/.style  = {draw,  drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
    onode/.style = {basic, thin, rounded corners=2pt, align=center, fill=green!60,text width=3cm,},
    tnode/.style = {basic1, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60},
}
%
\begin{document}
\title{Structure of Book}
\begin{forest} for tree={anchor=base west,
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=east,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,l sep+=1em,
    align=left, no edge
}  
[Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root 
  [{Applications to NCSs, CNs\\ GRNs}, no edge, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=bottom]
       [\textbf{Chapter 8}  CNs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 7} NCSs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 5} GRNs, tnode] 
  [{Analysis and Synthesis for \\ Systems with \\ Incomplete Information}, inner ysep=0pt, no edge, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=middle]
    [\textbf{Chapter 11} RVOs, tnode] 
     [{\textbf{Chapter 9} RONs},tnode]
    [{\textbf{Chapter 10} MMs},tnode]
    [\textbf{Chapter 6}  {MMs, SNs}, tnode]
    [{Analysis and Synthesis for\\ Systems with   General \\Engineering Phenomenon}, inner ysep=0pt, no edge, tikz={\node [draw, blue, fit=()(!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};}]
     [\textbf{Chapter 12} {TDs, GNs},tnode]
              [\textbf{Chapter 4} {TDs, MJ, SNs}, tnode] 
         [\textbf{Chapter 3} {TDs, MJ, NDs}, tnode]
         [\textbf{Chapter 2} {TDs, NDs}, tnode ,name=top] 
]
\node [draw,  black!40, inner sep=.4em, fit={(top)(middle)(bottom)} ] {};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root, calign=last` sufficient for you? `calign=last, yshift=.15cm` if you want it absolutely aligned to the top but this is hard coded though.

Comment: You have not explained, what problem you encounter and what you have tried in order to achieve your goal. Please clarify your question a bit and try to reduce the code to the absolute minimum. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my question and highlighted in the content as well

Comment: You still say "I encounter a problem when I try [...]". What problem and what have you tried? Did you check my approach from above? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical approach for this tree-style is to align the root with the child you want. In this case, it would be `calign=last`. If you want to align it to the grey box, you have to shift it a little bit manually. This could look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{%
    basic/.style = {draw, thin, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
    root/.style = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, fill=green!30, text width=2cm}, % I have deleted all the alignments here, as they get overwritten in your `for tree={}`
    onode/.style = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, fill=green!60, text width=3cm,},
    tnode/.style = {basic, fill=pink!60},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest} for tree={%
            ,anchor=base west
            ,grow=0
            ,l sep+=1em
            ,align=left
            ,no edge
        }  
        [Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root, calign=last, yshift=.15cm
        [{Applications to NCSs, CNs\\ GRNs}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=bottom]
        [\textbf{Chapter 8}  CNs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 7} NCSs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 5} GRNs, tnode] 
        [{Analysis and Synthesis for \\ Systems with \\ Incomplete Information}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=middle]
        [\textbf{Chapter 11} RVOs, tnode] 
        [{\textbf{Chapter 9} RONs},tnode]
        [{\textbf{Chapter 10} MMs},tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 6}  {MMs, SNs}, tnode]
        [{Analysis and Synthesis for\\ Systems with   General \\Engineering Phenomenon}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw, blue, fit=()(!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};}]
        [\textbf{Chapter 12} {TDs, GNs},tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 4} {TDs, MJ, SNs}, tnode] 
        [\textbf{Chapter 3} {TDs, MJ, NDs}, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 2} {TDs, NDs}, tnode ,name=top] 
        ]
        \node [draw,  black!40, inner sep=.4em, fit={(top)(middle)(bottom)} ] {};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As clarified in comment, you want to have all boxes in one line. So you have to put them onto the same level. To be honest, I do not see the point in using some tree here. But here you are:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest} for tree={%
            ,anchor=base west
            ,grow=0
            ,align=left
            ,no edge
        }  
        [       
        [{Applications to NCSs, CNs\\ GRNs}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=bottom]
        [\textbf{Chapter 8}  CNs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 7} NCSs, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 5} GRNs, tnode] 
        [{Analysis and Synthesis for \\ Systems with \\ Incomplete Information}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw,  blue, fit=() (!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};},name=middle]
        [\textbf{Chapter 11} RVOs, tnode] 
        [{\textbf{Chapter 9} RONs},tnode]
        [{\textbf{Chapter 10} MMs},tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 6}  {MMs, SNs}, tnode]
        [{Analysis and Synthesis for\\ Systems with   General \\Engineering Phenomenon}, inner ysep=0pt, tikz={\node [draw, blue, fit=()(!n) (!nn) (!nnn)(!nnnn), inner sep=1pt] {};}]
        [\textbf{Chapter 12} {TDs, GNs},tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 4} {TDs, MJ, SNs}, tnode] 
        [\textbf{Chapter 3} {TDs, MJ, NDs}, tnode]
        [\textbf{Chapter 2} {TDs, NDs}, tnode ,name=top] 
        [Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root, yshift=2cm, xshift=1cm] % shifting is optional here
        ]
        \node [draw,  black!40, inner sep=.4em, fit={(top)(middle)(bottom)} ] {};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you solved my problem, thanks. You are right. The truth is that I hide the path from the tree which is my original graph, but I don't want to make a major revision to my codes. Thanks!

Comment: You may like my code below which uses the brand new version of `forest` with `calign=child edge` - and it works! ;)

Comment: @cfr oh yes, I like it. Upvoted already. Great to have this issue fixed.

Comment: Note: No longer brand new :(. Although, eye-balling it, I guess there's nothing which should break.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of drawing the tree with the default direction of growth. Note that this requires `forest` version 1.09 (or, presumably, later).

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows,fit}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow},
    basic1/.style = {draw,  drop shadow, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
    tnode/.style = {basic1, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, rounded corners=2pt},
    fitbox/.style = {draw, gray, dashed, inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=7.5pt, rounded corners=2pt},
}
\forestset{
  fitting/.style n args=2{
    tikz+={\node (#2) [fitbox, fit=#1] {};},
    inner sep=0pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\title{Structure of Book}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=left,
    font=\sffamily,
    no edge,
    child anchor=north west,
    inner sep=1pt,
    if level=0{
      parent anchor=south,
      l sep+=5mm,
    }{
      calign=child edge,
      parent anchor=south west,
    },
  }
  [Nonlinear\\Stochastic\\Systems, root
    [\textbf{Chapter 2} {TDs, NDs}, tnode
      [\textbf{Chapter 3} {TDs, MJ, NDs}, tnode, name=widest
        [\textbf{Chapter 4} {TDs, MJ, SNs}, tnode
          [\textbf{Chapter 12} {TDs, GNs},tnode
          [{Analysis and Synthesis for\\ Systems with   General \\Engineering Phenomenon}, fitting={() (!u) (!uu) (!uuu)(!uuuu)}{f1}
    [\textbf{Chapter 6}  {MMs, SNs}, tnode
      [{\textbf{Chapter 9} RONs},tnode
        [{\textbf{Chapter 10} MMs},tnode
          [\textbf{Chapter 11} RVOs, tnode
          [{Analysis and Synthesis\\for Systems with\\Incomplete Information},  fitting={(!u) () ( -| widest.east) (!uu) (!uuuu) (!uuu)}{f2}
    [\textbf{Chapter 5} GRNs, tnode
      [\textbf{Chapter 7} NCSs, tnode
       [\textbf{Chapter 8}  CNs, tnode
       [{Applications to\\NCSs, CNs, GRNs}, fitting={(!uuu) () (!u) (!uu) ( -| widest.east)}{f3}, fitting={(f1) (f2) (f3)}{f4}
    ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: southerly growth]

Comment: You're a genius,  your code is more intuitive, I wish I can accept two answer.

Comment: @WangyanLi Thank you, although i think the package author is the genius! But the best thing about this answer is that it did not work. Figuring out why revealed a bug in the package which has led to a new version which fixes the problem. So if you use this, check the version of `forest`. It works with 1.09 but it will not work with earlier versions as the patch is an indirect result of your question! It is nice when a puzzling problem turns out to be a fixable bug and improves the software for everybody ;).